# How to make an object in a published OpenGraph story link to my app?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I've got a Facebook app that uses Opengraph stories. Clicking on a title or an image of a published story is supposed to link to my app (at least it does for many other apps and games I see on Facebook), but instead it opens the clicked object properties page. Where can I customize the link so that users who click on the object get directed to my app?

Comment: Open Graph identifies objects by their URL, and that URL is what the user gets taken to when they click on the link. If you see that for other apps it goes somewhere else, then they are _redirecting_ there after that URL is requested. (When doing so, one has to make sure that this redirect only happens for actual users, and not the Facebook scraper – either by using JavaScript to redirect, or recognizing the FB scraper server-side by its user agent.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, you made it very clear _what_ I should do, however, I still don't understand _how_ I can do it. Where exactly can I insert JavaScript into the object? I've tried copying the HTML code of the object and recreating it on my server, where I can change its contents, but even then my redirection link doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Are you using self-hosted objects, or objects created via the API Facebook provides? That’ll work for self-hosted objects only, of course.